# Was "ig" ever in the OSPD?

Tags: scrabble

I used to play in Scrabble tournaments about 30 years ago, but I still kept up with developments in tournament Scrabble until about 10 years ago through friends who still competed who are no longer available to answer this question.

I seem to recall that "ig" meaning "ignore" entered the OSPD at the same time as "za" meaning "pizza" but not only is "ig" not in the current OSPD or NWL, I can find no mention online of its ever having been there.

Did I dream this?

Comment: ig v. Alternative form of igg (“to ignore”). At least to https://en.wikwik.org/ig - but only a comment since I cant tell you if it was valid at one point

Comment: Thanks. That jogged my memory. It's "igg" not "ig." It entered the OSPD same time as "za" which caused me to recall them as both 2-letter words (as well as  both questionable IMHO).

Answer (score 4):

IG was not included in the [Changes in OSPD4](https://scrabbleplayers.org/w/OSPD4#New_Two-Letter_Word_Definitions_in_OSPD4), which included the addition of ZA. That version introduced five two-letter-words: FE, KI, OI, QI, and ZA.

That version did, however, also introduce the three-letter word IGG:

> IGG, IGGS, IGGED, IGGING
> v to ignore